# Margins not working with overflow-x?

Tags: html, css, meta

I'm making a mobile site, and need a banner at the top that completely horizontally covers the page and vertically doesn't show white space at the top. When I mange to disable the horizontal scroll, I can't make my banner how I need it to be.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#box {
    width: 110%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 15px;
}
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<title>testing</title>

<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7czac60u/4/) I basically need the white space around the blue box to go away.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the white space around the blue box is the margin around the body and html elements. Just set the margin on the body and html to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   margin: 0; /*added line*/
}
#box {
  width: 110%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 15px;
}
```

Also look the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/7czac60u/5/) example. For the future you don't need in jsfiddle to  declare `<html>`, `<body>` and `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good CSS reset from meyerweb,

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Place this at the top of your styles, just after the opening style tag. After that make sure to never use any value above 100% unless you have a very specific purpose (aka a complicated app needing modification/improvement), and I wouldn't use it even in the most dire of cases (I learned it the hard way).

After you set your resets, everything appears more sane and normal, and it should help you understand css better, aka, it's not always rational. Cheers!